# PowerQuery running very slow

Tags: powerquery

I noticed that my PowerQuery report can run very slow, and it's not only when refreshing, but when I 'Launch PowerQuery Editor' - it can take ~30 mins to get to the last last query in the report to see what has been loaded and then calculated.

The report is using 8 different .csv files as inputs (not very large, <1000 rows and <15 columns each).
Then on these inputs I make joins and grouping multiple times, but apart from that - there's no other 'heavy' calculations (only some sums, averages, percentages, some nested ifs).

So, I would have thought it shouldn't be too complex for PowerQuery to deal with it, but sometimes (not always???!!!) it takes really long to get 'inside'.
Yesterday I worked on it all day (almost :) as of course had also other jobs to do at work :)), and in the morning it took <1min to refresh, and then after launching PowerQuery Editor it was rather quick to get to every query in the report.
In the afternoon, with same inputs, it took ~3mins to refresh, and when I launched PowerQuery editor it took almost 30 mins to get to the last query in the report (my record wait time :O).

Do you know why this is happening?

I have a feeling that it will be something related to some settings of Excel/PowerQuery maybe?
But not sure where to start?

I also had a strange (???) situation when turninng off the annoying pop up message about the Privacy levels when using native databases (Data - Get data - Query options - Security sections - the first box needs to be unchecked):

I had it unchecked already, but after I showed it to my colleague - it took for me very long for the message about ignoring Privacy Levels to pop up (it shouldn't pop up, as I had the relevant bit unchecked???), then I had to tick that I wanted to ignore the Privacy Levels, and then it refreshed in normal time (that's all on the same PowerQuery report, just few days earlier).

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

Ania

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across these file corruption issues with PowerQuery in the past,
PowerQuery should not take that long to launch. Similar situation happened to me and I performed a MS Office Repair and rebuilt a new excel file which solved the issue.

Comment: Hi @BirdMan,Thanks for this, I know there will be at least several ways of improving the queries that I built, but ... I agree, it shouldn't take that long to perform calculations on a relatively small dataset.
I could re-built my report, but .. we are now moving with all the data to cloud storage, so probably won't spend anymore time on it now, as performing the calculations in the database/cloud storage application and then returning just the results to the report may improve things.

MS Office repair - haven't thought about it, so will check this too :)

Thank you :)